# $k$-element subsets of $[n]$

Tags: combinatorics

For $k = wr, w \geq 1$, how many $k$ element subsets of $[n] (1 \dots n)$ made up of $r$ disjoint $w$-tuples exist?

Suppose $w = 2, r = 3, n = 8$. In this case, $(12)(45)(67)$ would be one valid tuple.

My Ideas:
I tried a stars and bars approach, but I keep running into the problem of continuity.

Comment: When you say $w$-*tuple*, do you mean that order counts? Or do you just mean $r$ pairwise disjoint sets of cardinality $w$? In other words, is $(12)(54)(67)$ different from your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the $r$-set is ordered, and the $w$-tuples are unordered--for example, (12)(45)(67) and (12)(54)(76) are the same but (45)(12)(67) is different--multinomial coefficients suffice:

$${n \choose k} \cdot {k \choose w,w,w,\ldots,w} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot \frac{k!}{(w!)^r} = \frac{n!}{(n-wr)!(w!)^r}.$$

If the $r$-set is also unordered--so (12)(45)(67) and (54)(67)(21) are the same--then we need to divide by $r!$:
$$\frac{n!}{r!(n-wr)!(w!)^r}.$$